# Fiction book where a monster army has destroyed all human armies and is reaching the capital

Tags: story-identification, books

I only read the 1st few pages of the book but I remember them a little. The world is being destroyed by monsters (do not know what kind) and despite the world's effort it has been fruitless to stop them as all the armies have fallen. This seems to be a swords era. Not sure about magic. The king is standing in the balcony. His right hand man puts his hand on the king's shoulder. The book said had it been anyone else they would have been killed/had their cut down. But the right hand man was exempted as he was his partner from childhood. I think the monster army has reached the capital where the king is.